# Cannot start postgresql after ec2 instance restart

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I am a newbie in postgresql. A friend of mine is hosting a php script with postgresql db on an Amazon EC2 instance. He stopped the instance, and started it two months later. By default the EC2 instance does not have Postgresql running, so I tried:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

and got

```
Starting postgresql service:                               [FAILED]
```

Any guesses on how to have it up and running? The instance is running on a default Amazon Linux instance.

Comment: Can you check /var/log/syslog or the postgres logfiles to see what is going on? Can you start postgres in foreground mode?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. There is no log file related to postgres inside /var/log or any sub-folder. The only one is pgpool, and it does not write anything when postgresql is asked to start.

Comment: The logs are in the same location as the PostgreSQL datadir. If you can't find that, and there's no mention of PostgreSQL in /etc, either do `find / -name postgresql.conf` as root, or read the init script to see where it's pointing `pg_ctl` or `postgres` when starting. **It'd help a lot if you'd mention your distro, PostgreSQL version, and how you installed PostgreSQL**.

Comment: I get this: DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5433001, size=1880072192, 03600).
HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory or swap space. To reduce the request size (currently 18$
        The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.

Comment: Ok I got it, there were two problems. The permissions were set to 755 and they should be 700 with owner being postgres. Second it was consuming a lot of memory, so I should either add a more memory or configure smaller amounts in max connections and total memory in postgresql.conf

Answer (score 0):

The error mentioned in your logs can be fixed by reducing shared buffers or by increasing the kernel's shmem max settings.  Additionally as you noted PostgreSQL requires secure file permissions in order to start.   My recommendation is to start with smaller shared buffers and then figure out what you need.